Custom keyboard shortcut for switch to workspace is not working
version:  Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

In my settings -> keyboard -> keyboard-shortcuts -> Navigation ->
I set following custom shortcuts:
Switch to workspace 1: Super+1
Switch to workspace 2: Super+2

But, after these settings, when i click
Super+1 - First app on dock opens
Super+2 - Second app on dock opens

I don't know why my custom shortcuts are not overriding previous default shortcuts, also, I don't know where i can disable this default behaviour of super+num to open app on dock.
I tried sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade, logout, restart, still problem persists.

Use gnome shell extension sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions or preferably gnome shell extension manager sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager.
Open the application you installed (below is Shell Extension Manager).

Configure "Ubuntu Dock" and under Behavior and disable Use keyboard shortcuts ta activate apps.


Temporary fix:
After disabling "Ubuntu Dock" in my "Extensions" app, these 'switch to workspace' starts workings.
